# Bring helpdlg('helpstring') to front in MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, dialog, matlab-guide

I'm trying to popup a help window so the first thing the user sees would be a help window. But it stays in the back of my GUIDE window. I'm putting the code in my opening function.

```
% --- Executes just before layout is made visible.
function layout_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)
% Open the help dialog
helpdlg('My help message')

% opening code here...


guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to interrupt the execution of the OpeningFcn to show the window. To avoid long wait times after hitting "ok", you should put the help message at the end of the OpeningFcn.

```
% --- Executes just before layout is made visible.
function layout_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)
% Open the help dialog
h = helpdlg('My help message');

% opening code here...


guidata(hObject, handles);

%# optional: set(hObject,'visible','on')
%# if you want to have the GUI be visible when the dialogue pops up.

uiwait(h); %# wait for closing the window
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can set visibility to on, and call `figure(h)` afterward, if the help dialog shouldn't be modal.